# how is the lambda expression in bold below became valid even if only parenthesis is the argument

Tags: java, lambda

how is the lambda expression in bold below became valid even if only parenthesis is the argument

```
public class TargetTypeDemo {
    static void invoke(Runnable r) {
        r.run();
    }

    static <T> T invoke(Callable<T> c) throws Exception {
        return c.call();
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     * @throws java.lang.Exception
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String s = **invoke(() -> "done")**;

        System.out.println(s);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just how you write a lambda without any arguments.  Just like you would write a method

```
void run() {...}
```

you can just write a no-arg lambda

```
() -> {...}
```